# How to adjust the height of this menu?

Tags: html, css, button, menu, height

I got a nice menu that fits with my site. However when I add this menu into my page I cant seem to make it fill in in the lenght of the page vertical (it is vertical already just not very long in lenght)

The only way I manage to do this is to adjust the menu button their lenght which would make the lenght longer but the buttons will be ugly due to the height.

My CSS:

```
    .menu_simple ul {
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
    width:100px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.menu_simple ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white; 
    padding: 10.5px 11px;
    background-color: #BDBDBD;
    display:block;
}

.menu_simple ul li a:visited {
    color: white;
}

.menu_simple ul li a:hover, .menu_simple ul li .current {
    color: white;
    background-color: #5FD367;
}
```

My html:

```
   <div class="menu_simple">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

So I just want the menu to fill up vertical with just background if there isnt a code for a new menu button..

Hope its understandable what I mean, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Would this work?

## [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/r9GJT/1/)

Basically you need to set the height of the parent `div` to 100%, as well as the html and body elements so that the `div` has a reference point to size itself from. You then need to move the grey background from the menu items to the `div` itself to give a consistent appearance of a stretched menu. Setting `display:inline-block` on the `div` ensures its width is only that of the longest menu item, and not `100%` as is default block level behaviour.

CSS

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
div.menu_simple {
    height:100%;
    background-color: #BDBDBD;
    display:inline-block;
}
.menu_simple ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width:100px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.menu_simple ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 10.5px 11px;
    display:block;
}
.menu_simple ul li a:visited {
    color: white;
}
.menu_simple ul li a:hover, .menu_simple ul li .current {
    color: white;
    background-color: #5FD367;
}
```

Comment: +1 - but beware of the scrollbar appearing, due to the extended height of the menu. Could be resolved by setting height to 99% or 98%, or by setting {margin:0; padding:0;} for body and html.